# "I saw him TAKE it" and "I thought he KNEW it"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, infinitives

I'm confused by the use of these two tenses  "I saw him TAKE it" and "I thought he KNEW it" Why I saw him + infinity form verb but I thought he + past tense??

Comment: Your second sentence is not grammatical as written. It ought to be "I thought **he** knew it."

Answer (score 2):

These are just the constructions that those particular verbs happen to take.

"Think" takes a "that" clause, which is finite and therefore tensed (the "that" is often omitted):

> I thought [that] he took it.

"See" (in this sense) takes a non-finite clause (and if its subject is a pronoun, it is in the oblique case):

> I saw him take it.

You *can* say "I saw [that] he took it", but it has a rather different meaning: something like "I saw something that led me to conclude that he took it, but I didn't necessarily see him actually take it".